# Jasper Report with Map of the world and circles of different color as overlay on top of different countries

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, ireport

[image]

I've created a jasper report with the image and a set of small ellipse/circle on top of that image. The color of the small cirles has to change based on the data that is used for generating the report. So I created a style and applied that style to the ellipse element. Here is my style:

```
<style name="ZFieldStyle">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{value} < 2L]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#00ff00"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{value} > 2L]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#FF0000"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

And here is how I apply it to the ellipse:

```
           <ellipse>
                <reportElement style="ZFieldStyle" mode="Opaque" x="285" y="47" width="17" height="17" forecolor="#FF00FF" >

                </reportElement>
            </ellipse>
```

but I'm want to associate the circles to distinct data elements so that way when the conditional style is applied the value that is considered is the value that pertains to that country.

For your reference, the data that's passed is a JRDataSource that wraps a list of Country instances.

Instance 1.
name="Canada";
value=0;

Instance 2.
name="US"
value=3;

..etc. And the **value** field dictates what color is to be displayed on the circle on top of the image.

How can I do this in Jasper?

NB. All circles will show in the report. (nothing hidden) The question is about binding the i'th circle which is at position (x=34, y=90) to a specific data item and color it as c,
the j'th circle which is at position (x=8, y=12) to a specific data item and color it d...etc. 
Where c, d are colors.

I've a mvn + java + jasper project that I'm testing with here: It has 3 data Items and 3 circles already placed in the title section on top of an image.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5GhWVO8BNlcVlNaRHpodm1Hd0k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As I can understand that you want to display different-2 color on different-2 countries. Is this right?

Comment: @user1791574 Yes. Based on data that is sent from the server. I know the positions of the ellipses. I have a conditional style that tells what color to apply based on what value. How do I bind the incoming values to the circles?

Answer (score 1):

Set all ellipse at its place at initial time. And for every ellipse set "print when expression" based on your value. e.g:

```
<ellipse>
  <reportElement uuid="7c0a9248-b2a1-43ea-b329-ff2212845b4b" x="323" y="0" width="109" height="45" backcolor="#EF4141">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{value} == 3]]></printWhenExpression>
  </reportElement>
        </ellipse>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: - hey thanks for the try. PrintWhenExpression prints when a certain situation is true. The question is not to print ellipses during this event and not during that other event. The question is: how to know which color for which ellipse? and which ellipse is linked to which data item in a list/ row ? But in any case I put your code to get my hands dirty. None of the ellipses showed up. My finding is that only the first item is considered in the "printWhenExpression". I'll share my project via google drive - just a toy app that's used for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please provide used in this project or just provide maven dependency. Which version of jasper report are you using?

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
 <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
 <version>3.7.6</version>
 <type>jar</type>
 <scope>compile</scope>
 <exclusions>
  ...
 </exclusions>
</dependency>

Comment: there is no jrxml file in your demo file. Can you provide it?

Comment: There is. In the above link you'll see it, Here it is:  spring-jasper-integration / spring-jasper-integration / src / main / resources / tree-template.jrxml